# ValueError : x and y must be the same size

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have a dataset which i'm trying to calculate Linear regression using sklearn.
The dataset i'm using is already made so there are not suppose to be problems with it.
I have used train_test_split in order to split my data into train and test groups. 
When I try to use matplotlib in order to create scatter plot between my ttest and prediction group, I get the next error:

> ValueError: x and y must be the same size

This is my code:

```
y=data['Yearly Amount Spent']
x=data[['Avg. Session Length','Time on App','Time on Website','Length of Membership','Yearly Amount Spent']]
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=101)

#training the model

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lm=LinearRegression()
lm.fit(x_train,y_train)
lm.coef_

predictions=lm.predict(X_test)

#here the problem starts:

plt.scatter(y_test,predictions)
```

Why does this error occurs?
I have seen previous posts here and the suggestions for this was to use **x.shape** and **y.shape** but i'm not sure what is the purpose of that.

Thanks

Comment: The variable you are passing to `lm.predict` is capitalized, while the one you assigned at the top isn't. Are you sure you are passing the right data to lm.predict?

Comment: Check the sizes of `y_test` and `predictions` by calling `len(y_tests)` and `len(predictions)`. They probably do not match. Also make sure you're predicting on the right variable, since `x_test` and `X_test` are different things.

Comment: this happens because `y.shape[0]` and `x.shape[0]` is not equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using the `EcommerceCustomers.csv` dataset ([link here](https://github.com/bcbarsness/machine-learning/blob/master/EcommerceCustomers.csv))

In your original post the column `'Yearly Amount Spent'` is also included in the `y` as well as in `x` but this is wrong.

The following should work fine:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = pd.read_csv("EcommerceCustomers.csv")

y = data['Yearly Amount Spent']
X = data[['Avg. Session Length', 'Time on App','Time on Website', 'Length of Membership']]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=101)


# ## Training the Model
lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X_train,y_train)

# The coefficients
print('Coefficients: \n', lm.coef_)

# ## Predicting Test Data
predictions = lm.predict( X_test)
```

See also [this](https://www.kaggle.com/aryan348/ecommerce-customers-linear-regression])